# Why is the Typescript compiler compiling outside of my package?

Tags: javascript, typescript, tsc, monorepo

I have a monorepo with several packages and one library shared among them:

```
root/
  one/
  two/
  three/
  shared-lib/
    package.json
    tsconfig.json
```

**tsconfig.json**:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "rootDir": "src",
    "outDir": "build",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "declaration": true,
    "declarationMap": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "esnext",
    "jsx": "react"
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "**/node_modules/**",
    "node_modules",
    "build"
  ]
}
```

When I try to compile my library, I get errors in packages `one`, `two`, and `three`.

```
$ cd root/shared-lib
$ yarn run tsc -p tsconfig.json

../one/some/module/up/in/here:14:25 - error TS2307: Cannot find module ...
```

Why am I seeing those errors here? Why is `tsc` trying to compile stuff outside of the package I told it to compile?

Comment: Have you by accident defined some baseUrl in your tsconfig that does not point to the root directory (shared-lib in this case)?

Comment: What does your `tsconfig.json` file look like?

Comment: Copied `tsconfig.json` contents to question.

Comment: Make sure nothing in `shared-lib`  is importing something from from the other modules

Comment: Note that I'm using [lerna](https://lerna.js.org/) at the top level of the repo, but I'm not actually invoking any `lerna` commands when I see this behavior.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested, the root cause was that I inadvertently had references to `one/`, `two/`, etc. from inside `shared-lib/` (as a consequence of incompletely refactoring stuff into `shared-lib/`). Fixing those imports resolves the issue.